# How to solve greater & less / inequal equation

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

Two farmers, Eric and Josef where talking. "How many sheeps do you have?" asked Eric. "If I divide my sheeps in $2, 3, 4, 5,$ or $6$ groups, there will always be 1 sheep left." Josef answered. How many sheeps did Josef have if he had more than $100$, but less than $150$?

How do you solve this with an equation then?

The answer is $121$.

Comment: Try to expand your equalities first.

Comment: @servabat Can you give an example?

Comment: $\frac{x-1}{2} = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @servabat What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Then, do you know that $\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2}$ ?

Comment: @servabat Yes, so simplified x=x

Comment: Well, in every appart from the 2 first.

Comment: Well, then you are looking for the remainder of the integer (euclidian) division of x by 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. A way to solve that is to search the LCM of 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, find a multiple of it which is between 100 and 150, and to had 1 to it.

Answer (score 2):

We have$$x\equiv1\pmod2$$
$$x\equiv1\pmod3$$
$$x\equiv1\pmod4$$
$$x\equiv1\pmod5$$
$$x\equiv1\pmod6$$

Using [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) we have
$$x\equiv1\pmod{60}\implies x=60k+1$$
where $k\in\mathbb N$

Now I'll leave it to you!

Comment: And can you solve this without guessing? Without using a computer that follows an algorithm? With just pure mathematics?

Comment: How would you solve it then?

Answer (score 1):

Because the remainder is always $1$, we need to find $ n+1,$ where n divides $2\cdots6$. It is a factor of the LCM, that is, $60$. Becuase $2\cdot60+1$ is the only number in the range $100\le x \le 150$, $121$ is your answer.

Comment: This is a good idea. But not quite correct as written. One searches $n+1$ where $n$ is divisible by each of $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$. That is it is divisible by their least common multiple which is however $60$.

Comment: The edit howver resolves only one of two issues I pointed out; you say n divides 2...6 this is not what you mean to say; rather n is a multiple of each of $2$, ..., $6$, or you can say "is divisible by"   Also it is not a factor of the LCM but a multiple, or say the LCM is a factor of n.

Answer (score 0):

all equations are the same and they say $x-1=x-1$ after cancelling the common numerators, therefore we get all solutions $x$ with $100<x<150$

Comment: Can you please see my edit, because I'm not even sure if my equations are correct for the **original problem**